# Error when trying to debug my code

Tags: java

When I am trying to debug my code then I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-**plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project napier-am: Compilation failure
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with     the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: What have you tried regarding `Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE`?

Comment: @Jeet Singh Configure the Build Path for the Project and point the Java Libraries to JDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses *JAVA_HOME* to access Java's location on the machine. In Your situation You point it to JRE not JDK. Set properly JAVA_HOME environment variable and it will work.

If You want to have different location/version used for Maven only You can edit *mvn.bat* file with something like this.

```
set JAVA_HOME=<path_to_other_jdk>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `JAVA_HOME` path is not set. You need to set it as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk <version>`

Comment: My - JAVA_HOME- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
I am new in Maven. When I am trying to build then its showing build success but at the time of debugging giving above mentioned error

Comment: @GwynEvans it was my mistake. I edited it accordingly :)

Comment: Fair enough, now deleted. To the OP, using a JRE will let you run things, but you need a JDK to compile them.  Also, that's not a debug message, Maven is trying to compile something, so don't assume you've built it already.

Comment: Yeah Thanks. That was my mistake. Now I am able to build it

Answer (score 0):

Everything is said in the exception:

> Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6..\lib\tools.jar

Your maven task is trying to "compile" something, but can't find the Java compiler (JDK=Java Development Kit).

> Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE.

Instead it finds a JRE=Java Runtime Environment (which is used for running java programs, not compiling them).

> you can change the location of your Java installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable

You need to have a valid JDK version installed and your JAVA_HOME environment variable must point to this JDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Thanks for the clue..
Everyone is correct.
In my JDK version tools.jar was not available thats why I was getting this problem its not finding tools.jar, While JAVA_HOME varible is configured correctly.
Need to focus on only Tools.jar so that installed again java version (i am using java 6)
Now come on project--> go thru the build path and Make sure---- 
click on

installed jre
edit
jre home =C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25

give path accordingly for which Your OS is compatible